# PestPHP with Laravel Zero, Output not printed

Tags: php, laravel, testing, pestphp

I work on laravel forge cli, [this repository github](https://github.com/laravel/forge-cli/). I'm trying to add new functionality to this project, so I've created a new command below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Commands;

use Laravel\Forge\Resources\User;

class UserShowCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The signature of the command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'user:show';

    /**
     * The description of the command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Retrieving the current user';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->step('Retrieving the current user');

        $user = $this->forge->user();

        $this->table([
            'ID', 'Email', 'Name', 'Github', 'Gitlab', 'Bitbucket', 'DO', 'AWS', 'Linode', 'Vultr', 'Can create server ?'
        ], collect([[
            $user->id,
            $user->email,
            $user->name,
            $user->connectedToGithub ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            $user->connectedToGitlab ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            $user->connectedToBitbucket ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            $user->connectedToDigitalocean ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            $user->connectedToAws ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            $user->connectedToLinode ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            $user->connectedToVultr ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            $user->canCreateServers ? 'Yes' : 'No'
        ]])->all());
    }
}
```

Here's the return of my command in a terminal:

[image: screenshot of my terminal]

Then I wrote the test, inspired by what was already available for the others. Here it is:

```
<?php


use Laravel\Forge\Resources\User;

it('displays the current user', function () {
    $this
    ->client
    ->shouldReceive('user')
    ->andReturn(new User([
        'id' => 0,
        'name' => 'John Do',
        'email' => 'john@do.com',
        'cardLastFour' => '4444',
        'connectedToGithub' => true,
        'connectedToGitlab' => true,
        'connectedToBitbucket' => true,
        'connectedToBitbucketTwo' => true,
        'connectedToDigitalocean' => true,
        'connectedToLinode' => true,
        'connectedToVultr' => true,
        'connectedToAws' => true,
        'readyForBilling' => true,
        'stripeIsActive' => 1,
        'stripePlan' => 'yearly-basic-199-trial',
        'subscribed' => 1,
        'canCreateServers' => true,
    ]));

    $this
        ->artisan('user:show')
        ->expectsTable(
            [
                'ID',
                'Email',
                'Name',
                'Github',
                'Gitlab',
                'Bitbucket',
                'DO',
                'AWS',
                'Linode',
                'Vultr',
                'Can create server ?'
            ],
            [
                [
                    'id' => '0',
                    'email' => 'john@do.com',
                    'name' => 'John Do',
                    'connectedToGithub' => 'Yes',
                    'connectedToGitlab' => 'Yes',
                    'connectedToBitbucket' => 'Yes',
                    'connectedToDigitalocean' => 'Yes',
                    'connectedToLinode' => 'Yes',
                    'connectedToVultr' => 'Yes',
                    'connectedToAws' => 'Yes',
                    'canCreateServers' => 'Yes',
                ],
            ],
            'compact'
        )
        ->run();

});
```

But the return is as follows: my header line was not printed.

[image: screenshot test fail]

When I do a :

```
dd($this->output())
```

The return is an empty string. So I know that the output is empty in the test context, but outside the test context, everything works.

**EDIT:**

I found the answer thanks to @Kazz comment.
In fact, you should have put 3 spaces in front of the prefix of each header and each value.

My business logic below:

```
$this
        ->artisan('user:show')
        ->expectsTable(
            [
                '   ID',
                '   Email',
                '   Name',
                '   Github',
                '   Gitlab',
                '   Bitbucket',
                '   DO',
                '   AWS',
                '   Linode',
                '   Vultr',
                '   Can create server ?'
            ],
            [
                [
                    'id' => '   0',
                    'email' => '   john@do.com',
                    'name' => '   John Do',
                    'connectedToGithub' => '   Yes',
                    'connectedToGitlab' => '   Yes',
                    'connectedToBitbucket' => '   Yes',
                    'connectedToDigitalocean' => '   Yes',
                    'connectedToLinode' => '   Yes',
                    'connectedToVultr' => '   Yes',
                    'connectedToAws' => '   Yes',
                    'canCreateServers' => '   Yes',
                ],
            ],
            'compact'
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the table header does not match, there is different spacing when you run test, remove table style 'compact' to use default instead